# Using Static IP in Heroku for hosted Discord bot

Tags: heroku, ip, bots, discord

My bot uses an API with whitelist IP, and I would like my bot to have a fixed IP.

It's hosted on heroku, I have no idea how I can make the IP fix.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Heroku add-on called *Fixie*. They explain you everything [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fixie). You can also add it directly to your app [here](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/fixie). You have 500 requests per month for free, then you have to pay. You can also see all the IP addresses available to Heroku [here](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json).